# C# Anonymous function-scope

Tags: c#, lambda, anonymous-function

```
var foo = "bar";

new Func<String>(() => 
{
    var foo = ""; // This can't be done in C#. Why is that?

    /* In JavaScript, this is perfectly valid, since this scope (the anonymous
       function) is disconnected from the outer scope, and any variable declared
       within this scope will not affect variables in the outer scope */

})()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, even in javascript it *isn't entirely* disconnected; javascript allows lexical closures - so without the `var`, the old value of `foo` should still be available.

The difference is that javascript **chooses** to allow you to re-declare the name with a different meaning (in the inner scope). C# **chooses** not to.

I find the C# version less easy to get confused about! In particular when code (further down in the method) expects to be talking about the "old" variable, and suddenly it starts looking at the "new" one.

Answer (score 4):

C# captures local variables inside the anonymous function.  This is actually a very powerful feature that JavaScript also supports but in a slightly different way.

This concept is what computer scientists call a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)).  By capturing local variables they can become part of the state of the function itself thus giving you more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code refers to both symbols as "locals", the compiler cannot discover which you are referring to simply by going up the scope chain (local -> member -> type).

FYI, anonymous methods are compiled as classes and are assigned (as properties) any 
members/locals they access as fields.